# Find multiple solutions by changing direction and priority

Tags: cplex

With cplex, i want to solve a SAT problem several times and get different solutions by changing the directions (IloCplex.BranchDirection.Up | IloCplex.BranchDirection.Down) and priorities for the variables. However, I always get the same solution (several thousands exist).

I more or less do the following:

```
IloCplex solver = new IloCplex();
solver.addEq(...);
solver.addGe(...);
solver.addLe(...);

while (true) {
  Collections.shuffle(vars);

  for (IloIntVar var : vars) {
    solver.setDirection(variables.get(object), random.nextBoolean() ? IloCplex.BranchDirection.Up : IloCplex.BranchDirection.Down);
    solver.setPriority(variables.get(object), vars.indexOf(var));
  }

  solver.solve();

  for (IloIntVar var : vars) {
      value = solver.getValue(var);
  }
}
```

I want to get different (if feasible) values for each variable in each iteration. Someone sees where my fault is? I tried all solver.clear* methods to reset it, but this did not help.

Answer (score 1):

The branch priorities change which nodes get expanded on the branch-and-cut tree.  While you *might* get different solutions by changing them, there is no guarantee.  In fact, it's likely that the first solution found using heuristics at the root node and no branching occurs at all.  In the case of a pure 0-1 problem like you have, you can do the following

1. Solve for the first solution (x<sup>*</sup>)
2. Let y = sum of x<sup>*</sup>[i]
3. Add a constraint sum  (2 x<sup>*</sup>[i] - 1) x[i] <= y

Comment: You suggested to apply a local branching constraint. Great idea. +1

Answer (score 0):

CPLEX also has a solution pool feature for accumulating multiple solutions during the MIP optimization.  It has parameters to control the specifics, so you can instruct it to only accept solutions within a certain percentage of optimality.   Since the underlying one tree algorithm for the solution pool needs only one or two branch and bound passes to accumulate the requested solutions, this may run faster than repeatedly optimizing and adding constraints to exclude the previously found solution.    See the CPLEX documentation for the solution pool and populate procedure for more information.